# Tridion UI issues

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, experience-manager

When I click on the SDL Tridion icon (on top left corner of the page) to edit the components, I am facing with two issues.

1. After clicking the button, I am getting one more "SDL Tridion" button (Top left) inside the page wrapper. Button click does not perform any function and always says loading. Not sure how to remove this?
2. On the published page, I have got the relevant UI tags for the Component Presentations but when editing it is not wrapping the component presentation inside the box. Although when clicked around the component presentation, I can see the relevant component above and a small box on top of the page. Clicking on the blue icon the box, I can see the properties of that component presentation. My question is why it is not wrapping the component? Please note that if I create the tags to edit the component field inside that component presentation, the box wraps that editing field and I am able to edit it.

Comment: Is your page surfaced as a portlet via a Portal technology, or are you dynamically ajaxing content in?

Comment: No, neither of them.

Comment: It's hard to know for sure on point #2 without seeing the markup and related CSS/JavaScript. But it could likely be a validation issue as Nick suggests (e.g. span wrapping block elements). Do the borders work for you on a simplified example?

Answer (score 4):

The most likely reason for getting more than one SDL button is due to the SiteEdit INIT tag being included more than once on your page.  If you're going through a portal, it is possible that the portal page renders it and again so does the portlet.

I have also seen this when a page was hosted outside of Tridion and would render the SiteEdit bootstrap script (the stuff that the INIT tag transforms into), this "external" page Ajaxed the Tridion page into a div and also contained the INIT syntax.

Your issues could also be due malformed HTML on the page, such as a missing closing tag.

Another reason could be that jquerie's `.html()` or `.load()` functions actually strip off the html comments, hence removing the SiteEdit markup.

Finally, it is possible that some other custom JS is doing something weird that  interferes with proper rendering of the SiteEdit field markup.

I suggest removing pieces of your HTML and/or JavaScript to narrow down to the specific piece that is causing the issue.